# How do I modify certain array elements without affecting the others?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make a Java program where I change the elements of an array equal to 2, into 4, the ones equal to 4 into 8, and the ones equal to 8, into 2. I can't figure out how to change these elements in such way that I don't change the ones that have already been switched, therefore I just end up with a bunch of 2's.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prob8Array {
    static int n, i;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Nr of array elements:");
        n = reader.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Array elements:");
        int[] a = new int[n];

        for(i = 0;i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = reader.nextInt();
        }

        reader.close();
        for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
                if (a[i] == 2) {
                    a[i] = 4;
                }
                if (a[i]==4) {
                    a[i] = 8;
                }
                if (a[i]==8) {
                    a[i]=2;
                }
        } 
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
```

This is the best I could come up with, but it obviously doesn't work the way I'm trying to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `if` statements you allow more than one to be executed for a single array element. Change them to `if..else if..else` structure.

```
if (a[i] == 2) {
    a[i] = 4;
} else if (a[i] == 4) {
    a[i] = 8;
} else (a[i] == 8) {
    a[i] = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to make at most one change for each array element, which means that if any condition is `true`, you don't want to evaluate the following conditions. This can be achieved with if-else-if :

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (a[i] == 2) {
        a[i] = 4;
    } else if (a[i] == 4) {
        a[i] = 8;
    } else if (a[i] == 8) {
        a[i] = 2;
    }
}
```

An alternative option is to use a `switch` statement:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    switch (a[i]) {
    case 2:
        a[i] = 4;
        break;
    case 4:
        a[i] = 8;
        break;
    case 8:
        a[i] = 2;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use if, else if to avoid entering in every if ::

```
       if (a[i] == 2) {
            a[i] = 4;
        }
        else if (a[i]==4) {
            a[i] = 8;
        }
        else if (a[i]==8) {
            a[i]=2;

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the second `for-loop`, you can do it on the fly by using **Ternary Operator** like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prob8Array {
    static int n, i;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Nr of array elements:");
        n = reader.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Array elements:");
        int[] a = new int[n];

        for(i = 0;i < n; i++) {
            int value = reader.nextInt();
            a[i] = (value==2)? 4 : (value==4)? 8 : (value==8)? 2 : value;
        }

        reader.close();

        for (i=0; i<n; i++) System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
```

**Test**

[image]

Comment: @Decima if it helps please accept the answer by clicking on the green correct sign on the left side of the answer